# Django + Python, mostrar modal usando {% if %} no template

Tags: python-3.x, django, modal, django-templates

Estou fazendo uma verificação se há turmas ativas, caso não haja deverá apresentar um modal e não o form de cadastro, porém não esta funcionando:

***views.py:***

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.conf import settings
from .models import *
from .forms import *
from registrations.services import email, parentEmail

# CRIAR UM NOVO ALUNO
def create_student(request):
    form = StudentForm(request.POST or None)
    group = Group.objects.filter(active=True).first()
    show_modal = False

    if not group:
        show_modal = True

    if form.is_valid():
        group = Group.objects.filter(active=True).first()
        form.instance.group = group
        student = form.save()
        request.session['student_id'] = student.id
        return redirect('registrations:parent_student')

    return render(request, 'student-form-registration.html', {'form': form})
```

***student-form-registrations.html:***

```html
<!-- Modal Fim Inscrição -->
{% if show_modal is True %}
    <div id="modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="inscricaoEncerrada">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                            <div class="text-center bottom-border">
                                <img class="img-modal" src="{% static 'images/ilustra3.png' %}" />
                            </div>
                            <p class="text-modal text-center">Olá! As inscrições para a próxima turma da Estação Hack Teens estão encerradas. A próxima turma vai
                                acontecer nos dias 06 e 07 de Outubro, e as inscrições estarão abertas a partir do dia 03
                                de Setembro! Volte nessa data e não deixe de participar :) </p>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-primary btn-estacao">Voltar para Estação Hack Teens</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Creio que não esteja sabendo usar o `{% if %}` no template, alguém sabe como me ajudar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O código está ok - mas você não está passando a variável `show_modal` do Python para o template.

Isso tem que ser feito na linha que manda renderizar o template (e claro, pra cada variável que você quiser usar no template):

```
return render(
      request, 
      'student-form-registration.html',
      {'form': form, 'show_modal': show_modal}
)
```

Além disso, não faz muito sentido usar `if ... is True`  - funcionaria nesse caso, mas não em muitos outros e é mais feio que dizer "subir pra cima" em Português. O valor da variável já é "verdadeiro" - então é só usar a própria variável como expressão do `if`:

```
 {%  if show_modal  %}
```

Não precisa nenhuma outra comparação - essa dica é válida tanto para a linguagem de template, como para código Python e de várias outras linguagens.

Comment: +1 pelo pleonasmo no código, com certeza vou usar essa comparação futuramente. hahaha

Comment: Desculpa ai Dr. @jsbueno, mas valeu a explicação oksaoskaoskaoksaosk

Comment: Na verdade, o uso do `is True` vai além do problema estético no Python - já que valores que normalmente seriam verdadeiros em um `if` podem não ser exatamente o mesmo objeto que `True` (como o próprio número 1)  .

Comment: Faz sentido @jsbueno mt obrigado pela explicação, agora já esta dando certo vcs são demais!

Answer (score 3):

Aparentemente só falta expôr a variavel `show_modal` para o template.
Para isso bastaria apenas adicionar `show_modal` ao `render`.

```py
return render(request, 'student-form-registration.html', {
    'form': form,
    'show_modal': show_modal
})
```